# Wrong result when appending to a [][]int slice - CombinationSum problem

Tags: go

When I append to a slice of type [][]int, the result is not what I expected. I have code below that illustrates the problem and has a fix. But I would like to understand what exactly is going on

The functioning code is at https://play.golang.org/p/aeibeDW17z2
The one that is broken is at https://play.golang.org/p/eP5MiH1VjSu

This is from the leetcode problem
https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum

Could someone please explain what exactly is going on? I beleive its got to do with reuse of the backing array.. but don't really understand.

Thanks in advance

Problematic Code

```golang
    if target == 0 {
        fmt.Println("Current Result:", currResult)
        fmt.Println("Result Before:", result)

        r := append([]int{}, currResult...)
        fmt.Println("r=", r)


        //*result = append(*result, r)
    // if you uncomment above line and comment below, you will get right result - Why?
        *result = append(*result, currResult)


        fmt.Println("Result:", *result)
        return
    }
```

**Working Code**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

import "sort"

func combinationSum(candidates []int, target int) [][]int {
    sort.Ints(candidates)
    result := [][]int{}
    helper(candidates, target, 0, []int{}, &result)
    return result

}

func helper(candidates []int, target int, pos int, currResult []int, result *[][]int){

    if pos == len(candidates) || target < 0 {
        return
    }

    if target == 0 {
        fmt.Println("Current Result:", currResult)
        fmt.Println("Result Before:", result)

        r := append([]int{}, currResult...)
        fmt.Println("r=", r)


        *result = append(*result, r)
    // if you comment above line and uncomment below, you will get wrong result - Why?
        //*result = append(*result, currResult)


        fmt.Println("Result:", *result)
        return
    }

    // lets see if we can optimize this call

    for i := pos; i < len(candidates); i++ {
        temp := append(currResult, candidates[i])
        helper(candidates, target-candidates[i], i, temp, result)

    }
}


func main() {

    candidates :=[]int{2,3,5}
    target := 8

    fmt.Println("Input:\n-----\n","Target:", target, "Candidates:", candidates )
    //fmt.Println("Target:", target, "Candidates:", candidates)

    fmt.Println("\nDebug\n-----")
    result :=combinationSum(candidates, 8)

    fmt.Println("\n\nResults:\n------\n", result)


}
```

Comment: The code that works copies `currResult`s backing array to the result.  The code that does not work shares the backing arrays between the result and computation in progress.

Comment: Thank you.. Since the array that was shared was updated by the caller and it just points to the latest copy of the array...